# No commands with a binding that start with C-c C-x

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, mode-specific-map

With a vanilla emacs 29.0.50, if I hit <kbd>C-c C-x</kbd> it hangs waiting for another key but if I hit <kbd>C-h</kbd> the `*Help*` buffer only contains:

```
No commands with a binding that start with C-c C-x
```

I tried with a stable 28.1 emacs and I have the same behaviour.

Which part of emacs is responsible for binding <kbd>C-c C-x</kbd>? It looks like it's Org but if I'm in an org file <kbd>C-c C-x</kbd> allows me to do multiple things while when I'm on any other file it's just empty.

Is there a bug in org mode that makes its keymap available everywhere?

[EDIT] I'm starting emacs with `emacs -Q`

Comment: Does it hang if you start with `emacs -Q`? If not, your own init file is at fault: bisect it to find out the culprit.

Comment: What is the major mode of the buffer you are in when you do `C-c C-h`?

Comment: Sorry @NickD, what I called "vanilla emacs" was calling emacs with -Q. And the major mode is the main scratch mode so `lisp-interaction-mode`

Comment: @Drew Interesting. Well, I'll unbind it and keep going with my things then :-)

Comment: @Drew It's a feature, see my answer. The closest thing to a bug here is that `help-char` doesn't know what's going on (but I suspect it would be difficult to handle all the translation maps correctly). There's no binding of `C-c C-x` anywhere, the binding is for `C-x` itself, and by design that binding takes effect even after a prefix.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Thx. Actually, there are several mode-specific bindings of `C-c C-x` - for commands, not for `ctl-x-map`. You can see them if you grep the Lisp sources for `C-x` (and then search the output for `C-c`). But in those modes `C-c C-x` won't just wait for another key.

Comment: @Drew Yes, sure. I meant there's no binding of `C-c C-x` anywhere in the running state of Emacs, i.e. no binding of `C-c C-x` in any active keymap, if you just start `emacs -Q`, even though it looks like it since `C-c C-x` waits for another key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason `C-x` seemingly appears in every keymap is that it's in [`key-translation-map`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-key_002dtranslation_002dmap) and [`function-key-map`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-local_002dfunction_002dkey_002dmap). These are some of several keymaps that translate input before it gets to the “real” keymaps (global map, major mode map, minor mode maps).

`key-translation-map` has bindings starting with the prefix `C-x 8`, which is bound to [`iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.2/lisp/international/iso-transl.el#L271). This contains bindings to [insert characters that you might not have on your keyboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html#index-curved-quotes_002c-inserting). For example, you can type `C-x 8 ' e` to insert é. Due to the way the input is translated, in most contexts, this is equivalent to pressing the `é` key. For example, if you bind a command to `C-c é` (convenient if you have e.g. a French keyboard), you can invoke that command with `C-c C-x 8 ' e` (convenient if you're temporarily on an English keyboard).

`function-key-map` has bindings starting with the prefix `C-x @`, which is bound to an [unnamed keymap containing `even-apply-XXX-modifier`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.2/lisp/simple.el#L8609) bindings. These allow you to type keys with modifiers that you might not have on your keyboard. For example, you can type `C-x @ m f4` to run whatever command is bound to `M-f4` even if your operating system intercepts that binding before it reaches Emacs. (This doesn't work for `M-tab` due to the way Emacs handles <kbd>Tab</kbd> internally: Emacs's `TAB` is actually `C-i` like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and the binding for `M-TAB` is the binding for `C-M-i`. The translation of `tab` to `C-i`, and similar translations with modifiers, are in `local-function-key-map`.) Due to the way the input is translated, in most contexts, this is equivalent to pressing the target key. For example, if you bind a command to `C-c M-f4`, you can invoke that command with `C-c C-x @ m f4`.

If there's a non-prefix binding, it takes precedence over the translations from these keymaps, which is why for example `C-x C-x` is a possible binding (`ctl-x-map` has a non-prefix binding for `C-x`, so the second `C-x` doesn't give the `C-x 8 …` or `C-x @ …` bindings a chance). A prefix binding in a normal map can coexist with a prefix binding in a translation map; for example both `function-key-map` and `global-map` have bindings for `C-x 8 something` (for disjoint sets of `something`).

The automatic help system from pressing `C-h` (`help-char`) after a prefix key isn't aware of translation maps, which is why it doesn't help here. Help commands like `describe-key` that expect a complete (non-prefix) binding do report whatever the binding is for, even if it's for a function in a translation map rather than an interactive command in a normal map. So for example `C-c c C-x 8 ' e` reports that “é (translated from C-x 8 ' e) runs the command self-insert-command”.

Comment: Good answer. Thx. It's too bad that `C-c C-x C-h` doesn't help here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. Like @Drew said it's sad that `C-h` doesn't help here but at least I now know what's happening behind the scene.

Comment: Really cool trivia, and very thoroughly explained. I was always aware of the `C-x 8` bindings and used them a lot to *type* foreign characters, but I had no idea they could be used in a key sequence.